# A way to get a "button press event" for a WPF ScrollViewer control

Tags: wpf, user-controls, mouseevent, scrollviewer

My custom control uses a `ScrollViewer` and I want to determine when the user presses the horizontal scroll increment button *while* the control is already scrolled to the horizontal max.

The viewer contains a canvas and the idea is the canvas will extend if the user tries to scroll past its extent with the buttons.

`ScrollViewer` doesn't appear to have any events which relate to the buttons specifically and `ScrollChanged` is no use on its own since it doesn't trigger when the bar is at its extent.

.Net Reflector hasn't yielded much of use. The closest I can get is adding an event handler for mouseLeftButtonDown, I can see the viewers state but not how to determine whether the mouse event originated from the button.

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to get the buttons of the control via the `VisualTree` and attach a handler to their click events.

Edit: I wrote an extension method for getting items of visual tree via a path:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static DependencyObject GetVisualChildFromTreePath(this DependencyObject dpo, int[] path)
    {
        if (path.Length == 0) return dpo;
        List<int> newPath = new List<int>(path);
        newPath.RemoveAt(0);
        return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dpo, path[0]).GetVisualChildFromTreePath(newPath.ToArray());
    }
}
```

If your `ScrollViewer` is called sv you should be able to get the buttons like this:

```
RepeatButton button1 = sv.GetVisualChildFromTreePath(new int[] { 0, 2, 0, 0 }) as RepeatButton; //Up
RepeatButton button2 = sv.GetVisualChildFromTreePath(new int[] { 0, 2, 0, 2 }) as RepeatButton; //Down
RepeatButton button3 = sv.GetVisualChildFromTreePath(new int[] { 0, 3, 0, 0 }) as RepeatButton; //Left
RepeatButton button4 = sv.GetVisualChildFromTreePath(new int[] { 0, 3, 0, 2 }) as RepeatButton; //Right
```

Note: Buttons only exist if the respective scollbar is enabled. The extension method could probably improved in terms of performance by using other datatypes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added a handler to my ScrollViewers Loaded event which finds the horiztonal ScrollBar (once initialized), then the button with the appropriate command (LineRight) from this. I then add a handler to the Click event and it works perfectly.